# Multiple apps use one service

Tags: android, service

I have two apps - A app and B app(or more) , and I want all my apps to upload the apps in the user's phone when user add a new one.

All my apps have a service named MyService. In MyService has a BroadcastReceiver for Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED, when A app is installed in the user's phone first, then B app is installed. Only MyService in A app will be run and received Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED when a app is installed, just like AccountAuthenticator service.

My question is how can I start MyService in B app, when A app is deleted? (I can't listen if A app is deleted, cause maybe I will have C app in future).

Sorry for my poor English...